# Evaluate("COUNTIF(A2:A65536, "Yes")") doesn't work. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

`Evaluate("COUNTIF(A2:A65536, "Yes")")` doesn't work.

I've been staring at this function for a while now. Why doesn't VBA like my function? It says that it is missing an end parenthesis.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I expect it to count the number of Yes in the range A2:A65536

Comment: I hadn't tried it before, but that still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was the wrong way to escape quotes for VBA. I only guessed.

Comment: @user1283776 Don't forget to pick an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add additional quotes for the quotes around "Yes". Double quotes are the Excel-VBA-way to handle quotes inside a string. This should work for you:

```
Evaluate("COUNTIF(A2:A65536, ""Yes"")")
```